# file sync between user computer app and our servers --- skills needed --

Tags: networking, filesystems, synchronization, connection

we need to hire a coder to so the file sync work between:

: our severs and user computer and  vice verse -- so that files are always in sync: some way as dropbox does it --

So what would be the coding and expertise knowledge we should be looking for when hiring a coder for this job?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Networking, rsync, Linux, Windows, filesystem layout, DB knowledge... can think of many more

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned skills that mguillech mentioned are all good if you're looking to hire outside help.  Though if all you need is to make sure that file systems are in sync, you can just have a robocopy script scheduled to run periodically to mirror directories

For example: `robocopy c:\dir1 d:\dir2 /mir`

The /mir will make sure the destination looks just like the source (meaning it will delete any files/folders in the dest not in the source).